# Blender 2.49b crashes instantly when i try to open it

Tags: error

As the title describes, i open it and it says it all good and that it found the correct python version and then instantly crashes.
I really need to use this older version as i read it can import .x files and the plugin for newer versions able to do that seems to be broken.
Anyone who has any idea of why this is happening?

I figured out this is the case for every version before 2.72

Comment: Blender 2.49 is quite old and outdated, it probably has difficulty in running on newer platforms with new OS and modern hardware that requires different OpenGL Versions.